# I have a Nintendo 64 bought in South America and want to play it in Europe

Tags: nintendo-64

I purchased an N64 about 19 years ago in South America and I've got about 20 games that worked on it before.

I now live in Europe (France) and would like to get my console working but I haven't figured out how.

Note that i purchased new RCA cables for it since I lost the original ones and I also purchased an RCA to HDMI converter but all I get when I turn the console on is a blue screen.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The N64 could output 3 different video formats

- NTSC - Japan / US
- PAL - Europe / South America
- PAL-M - Brazil

PAL-M except for the name is actually closer in specification to NTSC [PAL-M Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL-M#Compatibility).  There were other differences between the countries so region compatibility is complicated. The console and games will probably work better together (compared to European Console and South American games).

It also appears that your RCA to HDMI converter may be the reason for the Blue screen. [GameFaqs Forum](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/916387-nintendo-64/76065983)

**The remaining question is how to play the games.**
From my research (not experience) I suggest the following:

- Treat the console as though it outputs NTSC.
- Find an adapter for NTSC to HDMI?

It will either :

1. Work correctly with full color (South America excluding Brazil)
2. OR Will be monochrome (Brazil) in which case you will need to find a PAL-M adapter.